# Active tab pointing to inactive tabs using CSS?

Tags: html, css, tabs

Is there a way, using CSS, to make it so that when clicking a tab (as shown in the diagram below), the tab "points" to an inactive tab?

I'm trying to make it so that the green Tab 1 (in the diagram below) points to Tabs 2 and 3, and then if you click Tab 2, it points to Tab 3. However, when you click Tab 3, it would remain rectangular (with no arrow).

I have been trying various Stack Overflow snippets which successfully place the arrow above or below the tab, but none seem to work in overlapping the inactive tab next to the active tab.

This is the basic structure of my HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li class="active">
    <a href="#">Tab 1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Tab 2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Tab 3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

As for the CSS, I've been using snippets like this one: https://codepen.io/mimoYmima/pen/MwzQym

---

The issue I've been running into seems to be that, because the tabs are floated left, I can't make the active tab's arrow overlap the other tabs.

[image: Active tab pointing to inactive tabs]

Comment: overlapping is your last problem. **Preserve gradients** is the worst problem here. Have you tried to create something out of that codepen example?

Comment: Also... how does your *"diagram"* looks like when "Tab2" is selected?

Comment: Thanks guys. Per my diagram, when I click "Tab 2", it would adopt the same angled active tab as "Tab 1." But then for "Tab 3", I would have it just be green rather than have it point anywhere. Nevermind the gradients for now - this was just a quick Photoshop job to illustrate the tabbed look.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan What do you mean by preserve gradients and does my answer solve this?

Comment: @ChrisBeaman does my answer solve your problem?

Comment: @RachelGallen. Only the tabs with the `.active` class seem to be desired to have the arrow save the very last tab which should just be colored green. I took a stab at it below.

Comment: @basement yes your answer does solve it! Thank you! Only problem is, I'm working with a CMS that doesn't let me insert the type of HTML you have in your example. Nonetheless, for the sake of every other reader, your solution works great. Thank you.

Comment: @ChrisBeaman show me what your html looks like. Perhaps we can solve things with only CSS

Comment: @ChrisBeaman with CSS psuedo elements you may be able to create the necessary elements without touching the markup ( html ).

Comment: Thanks @basement. The HTML I'm using is above, in the question. Thanks

Comment: @ChrisBeaman glad you figured it out. I recently updated my answer to use pseudo classes and leave your HTML markup the same. Looks like you've gotten ample help for your problem lol.

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage a pseudo element with absolute positioning as the arrow for the active tab. It will be hidden unless the list item is given the 'active' tab. Original HTML markup remains untouched.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
body {
  display: flex;
}
ul {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #eee;
  background-image: linear-gradient( #fff, #ddd);
  border-radius: 1rem;
  border: 1px #888 solid;
  font-weight: bold;
}
li {
  float: left;
  padding: 1.5rem 4rem;
  border-right: 1px #aaa solid;
  position: relative;
}
li:last-child {
  border: none;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}
.active {
  background-color: #0b0;
  background-image: linear-gradient( #0b0, #090 );
}
li.active::after {
  content:'';
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  background-color: #eee;
  position: absolute;
  border: none;
  transform: scaleX( 0.75 ) rotate( 45deg ) translate( -50% );
  top: 50%;
  right: -2.45rem;
  margin-top: -0.45rem;
  border-top: 1px #888 solid;
  border-right: 1px #888 solid;
  background-color: #0b0;
  background-image: linear-gradient( 130deg, #0b0, #090 );
  border-top-right-radius: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="active">
    <a href="#">Tab 1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Tab 2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Tab 3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add triangle using pseudoelement to active tab and other to simulate triangle border. Demo:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul > li {
  padding: 10px 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 24px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-right: none;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fdfdfd, #828282);
}

ul > li.active {
  background: #66d835;
  position: relative;
}

ul > li.active:before,
ul > li.active:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

/* triangle border for active tab */
ul > li.active:before {
  transform: translateX(1px);
  border: 30px solid transparent;
  border-left-color: #000;
  z-index: 1;
}

/* triangle for active tab */
ul > li.active:after {
  /* border-width equal half of the height */
  border: 30px solid transparent;
  border-left-color: #66d835;
  z-index: 2;
}

/* border-radius for first tab */
ul > li:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}

/* border-radius for last tab but not active */
/* and right border */
ul > li:not(.active):last-child {
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

ul > li > a {
  height: 100%;

  /* styles for text centering */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

ul > li > a,
ul > li > a:hover,
ul > li > a:active,
ul > li > a:visited {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="active">
    <a href="#">Tab 1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Tab 2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Tab 3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What about the gradient inside the active tab? How would you achieve this?

Comment: @basement I don't see any gradients in OP's task or picture, but I would use SVG or `clip-path` in this case.

Comment: The active ( green ) tab has a slight light to dark gradient as the inactive ones do. That's the difficult aspect with this method. I'd prefer a method with more control over continuous background properties of both the arrow and the primary tab1 rectangle. I agree with you that SVG is probably the best solution here. My answer isn't perfect either.

Comment: @basement Just to be honest there is another way to add gradient here: add gradient for active tab rectangle, and draw triangle not via border technique, but as rotated rectangle and add the same gradient but with other angle. But this technique is rather tricky to bother about it without special requirements:)

Comment: See the technique I used in my answer. I did something very similar.

Comment: @basement Cool but I would do this only when OP asks. Don't see big popularity of this question to change something. Also this will make answer more complicated.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to float the arrow divs.

I have forked the codepen you linked to and edited the CSS to create the effect in the graphic you've shared. Here's my edited version:

https://codepen.io/sigil/pen/YxWZGa

```
<!-- language: lang-css -->
/* Button-arrow CSS: */
.arrow {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  padding-left: 2em;
  padding-right: 2em;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}
.arrow:after {
  border-left: 20px solid white;
}
.arrow.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.arrow.active,
.arrow.active:after {
  z-index: 50;
  border-left: 20px solid yellow;
}
.arrow.active:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  margin-right: -20px;
  right: 0;
}
.arrow:hover,
.arrow:active {
  background: yellow;
  color: black;
}
.arrow:hover:after,
.arrow:active:after {
  border-left: 20px solid yellow;
}

/* General styles to set a baseline 'look' - not related to the button-arrow CSS above */
body, html {
  font-family: helvetica;
  background: #333;
  color: #CCC;
}
.content {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

a:visited, a:link {
  color: #F93;
}
<!-- language: lang-html -->

<html>
<body>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Button with an arrow on the right. Just uses an anchor tag and css, so you can use it with your existing buttons easily by just adding the class of "arrow"! Also includes a hover state.</p>

    <a class="arrow active">Arrow</a><a class="arrow">Arrow</a><a class="arrow">Arrow</a>
  </div>
</body>
</html>

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Comment: This solution is the one that worked best for me. Thanks for your help @sigil!

Comment: You're welcome, glad it helped. Shame I got voted down even by others. :(